# Update Netbeans 8.1 module project template

Tags: netbeans

How do you update a netbean modules project template after you make changes to the project you used for the template.

I saw a blog post from 2007 saying to modify the build.xml but the way its shown is completely different to what things are now.

Blog post: https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/managing-netbeans-project-templates

I would hope recreating the entire module from scratch wouldn't be the standard way by this time nearly 12 years later.